# Blended or hierarchical objectives if solving speed is more important

Tags: optimization, mixed-integer-programming, python, multi-objective-optimization, assignment-problem

When optimizing a two objective task assignment problem, is it generally better to use blended objectives or hierarchical objectives if

- the speed to obtaining a near-optimal solution is more important than getting the optimal results
- it does not really matter whether we choose blended objectives (ratio of weights are not important) or hierarchical objectives (priority is not important)

Comment: I would be surprised if there is a "generally better" choice -- meaning I would expect each alternative to be faster some times, slower sometimes and roughly the same speed sometimes.